# I have a VBA in excel to transfer data to MySQL, however I have issues with the date

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, vba

I have a VBA in excel to transfer data to MySQL, however I have issues with the date. The error I get is

> Runtime Error: 2147467259 (8004005): Incorrect datetime value: for
>   function str_to_date.

This is my code:

```
sql = "Insert Into LeadBoard(Commodity,Last_Broadcast_Job,Material_to_Work, " _         & " Last_Picked_Job,Picked_Lead_Time,Last_Loaded_Job," _         & "Loaded_Lead_Time,Dispatch_Lead_Time,Last_Dispatched_Job," _         & "Out_of_Dock_Time,Last_Dispatched_Rack," _         & "Last_Dispatched_Trailer,Customer_Point_of_Install,Excel_date_time, calc_Material_to_work," _         & "calc_Load_Lead_Time, calc_Picked_Lead_Time,calc_Dispatch_Lead_Time) " _         & " VALUES (" & Commodity & "," & Last_Broadcast_Job & ",'" _         & Material_to_Work & "'," & Last_Picked_Job & ",'" _         & Picked_Lead_Time & "'," & Last_Loaded_Job & ",'" _         & Loaded_Lead_Time & "','" & Dispatch_Lead_Time & "'," _         & Last_Dispatched_Job & "," & "STR_TO_DATE('" & Out_of_Dock_Time & "', '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s'  ) ," _         & Last_Dispatched_Rack & "," & Last_Dispatched_Trailer & "," _         & Customer_Point_of_Install & "," & "STR_TO_DATE('" & FILEDATETIME1 & "', '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s' ) ," _         & calc_Material_to_work & "," & calc_Loaded_Lead_Time & "," & calc_Picked_Lead_Time & "," & calc_Dispatch_Lead_Time & ");"
```

Comment: well, what value is in `Out_of_Dock_Time` when the error occurs? Or maybe the problem is with `FILEDATETIME1`.One of these variables, or possibly even both, is likely to be the issue

Comment: The value for Out_of_Dock_Time is 04/10/18 17:26. and will be in this format itself.  The format for Fieldatetime1 is 04/10/18 17:26: PM

Comment: Hi @ADyson This is how I have defined my Out_of_dock time, could this be the reason? Out_of_Dock_Time = Format(XLsheet.Cells(i, CommodityCOl + 10).Value, "MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss")

Answer (score 1):

Your format string

```
'%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s'
```

is incorrect. As per the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) on date format specifiers, `%h` represents hours in 12hr format (i.e. 01-12). Instead you need to use `%H` to read 24hr times. The correct format string is

```
'%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s'
```

[Click here for a demo using SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/68953)